# Envy 4500 printer not scanning

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner

I have an HP ENVY 4500 e-all-in-one printer. It installed & prints successfully. But the scanner function does not work. Simple Scan says no scanner detected. I ran the command `sudo sane-find-scanner` & the scaner was also not detected.

I tied upgrading my hplip driver to the latest version, but it fails with an error that GCC is not installed. But I know for a fact GCC is installed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I tried doing this as sudo, but still did not work. I also edited the dll.conf file for sane. Since no help from ubunu users, I tried this answer that worked on my Arch system, but unsuccessfully on my Ubuntu 13.04 system.: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sane#For_HP_hardware

Comment: I'd try uninstalling gcc manually on Synaptic, reboot, and then installing gcc again using Synaptic.

Comment: Yea, tried that already. No luck.

Comment: Uninstall libsane, reboot and install libsane.

Comment: Did that too. Let me clarify, I uninstalled ALL dependencies, then reinstalled them. None of that worked.

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using and what version of hplip are you using?  Please describe the method you used to upgrade your hplip driver?

Comment: purge and remove gcc as well as the appropriated kernel-header packages. Than rerun the hplipo  installer see what it thells you and do it. This should fix the issue If you need assistence to determine your kernel version ask here again or simplle use sudo uname --a

Answer (score 3):

Try this: it worked for me. I have the same printer and had same issues until I used the terminal command `hp-setup`.

For more information https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sane#For_HP_hardware

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the following steps resolved my issue. Setup the printer with:

```
hp-setup
```

and scan your document with:

```
hp-scan
```

Answer (score -1):

Just bought an HP Envy 4500.  Worked out of the box with Ubuntu 14.04LTS - print, copy, scan.  Simply added it as a printer with hplip.

Comment: John, would you mind adding some details?  I'm trying to set up a 5660, but hp-setup won't see it at all.  A detail of Step 1, 2, 3, etc., would be great.  Thank you.